# Is it possible to get event when system downloading update or apps from Google play updating?

Tags: android

Want to get event when system starting to download new update or google play apps updating. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add a receiver in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name=".AppUpgradeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Next you need to add a receiver to handle these events:

```
class AppUpgradeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (context == null) {
            return
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "Updated to version #${BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE}!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED).

If you're looking for info on how to test these events, or further information on how it is triggered, you may find [my original post interesting](https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/how-to-create-and-test-an-app-update-listener/). It covers the use case of listening to your app's updates (`MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` vs `PACKAGE_REPLACED`), and has [an example repo](https://github.com/JakeSteam/UpdateListener) / [gist](https://gist.github.com/JakeSteam/4561f0f46a7b08be50785a72559f8fef).

Comment: what about system update event? Is it possible?

Comment: Please raise a new question if you have a new question (and mark this one as answered if it is) :)

Comment: It's not a new question. Please read the title.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I can't see an event in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#constants_1), I suspect it's because different manufacturers handle it differently.